# How to make a library project that provide services for other APP to use?

Tags: java, android, service, permissions, library-project

Is there any way to create a Service in a library project for other APP to use through a .jar file?

Currently I'm doing it this way:

1. Create a Android library project with package name "com.m2x.myservice", write a Service class "MyService". When it's compiled, I got a "myservice.jar" file in the "bin/" directory.
2. Create a Android application project, e.g. "DemoApp"
3. Move the "myservice.jar" file to The DemoApp's libs directory.
4. Add this to AndroidManifest.xml of DemoApp:

   ```
   <service android:enabled="true"
       android:name="com.m2x.myservice.MyService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.m2x.myservice.MyService" />
       </intent-filter>
   </service>
   ```
5. Call startService(new Intent("com.m2x.myservice.MyService")); to start the service in DemoApp.

But when I runs DemoApp, I got a runtime error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.demoapp/com.example.demoapp.MainActivity}:     java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent{   act=com.m2x.myservice.MyService (has extras) } without permission private to package
```

Who can tell me what am I doing wrong? And what's the correct way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it turns out that nothing is going wrong, the workflow is just fine.  Fix the AndroidManifest.xml will solve the problem